# Issue with many-to-many relationship in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I've a strange problem with adding many-to-many relation in Flask app.Everything seems to be ok because when I use the code below in "Python Console" (PeCharm) I see a new relation in my database.

```
f = CAR.query.filter_by(ID_CAR=1).first()
m = MANAGER.query.filter_by(ID_MANAGER=1).first()
f.CAR_MENAGO.append(m)
db.session.commit()
```

but when I want to do it in Flask app using WTForms, nothing happen, I don't get any error even. Do You know what should I add to this code below ?

```
@app.route('/test1',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def test1():
    form = test()

    id_car = form.ID_CAR.data 

    f = CAR.query.filter_by(ID_CAR=id_car).first()
    m = MANAGER.query.filter_by(ID_MANAGER=1).first()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        f.CAR_MENAGO.append(m)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('test1.html',form=form)
    return render_template('test1.html',form=form)
```

Template code:

```
{% extends "dashboardmanager.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/test1">
        {{message}}
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.ID_CAR) }}

          <button class="btn btn-success btn-xsy" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you sure the control goes inside the `if` block?

Comment: What You mean ? As I sad it doesn't work but if put it manually in "Python Console" it works (the very first bunch of code)

Comment: Can you put a `print` statement inside `if form.validate_on_submit():` and check if it is getting printed?

Comment: I put the "print" statement just below "if form.validate_on_submit():" and got a message. I also put "message='test'" in "return render_template('test1.html',form=form)" inside if statement.

Comment: So does it return `test` in place of the `message` in the template?

Comment: Yes, but my db is still empty. I will do some print screen, as a prove :) when I back home. I  tired use:`db.session.add(f)` but I got only errors.

Comment: [link](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AvdPsdAoxFQkg61eIzmwSr0ORcS34w)  I put the message inside `if` statement `return render_template('test1.html',form=form,message='stackoverflow.com:)')`

Comment: I know what was wrong. I kept the whole tables in another python file (as a module) and imported to the main python file. Now when everything is in one file,it works :) I hope this case will help someone.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case though as long as you are importing those at the start your file itself. Can you show us the way you imported those before and now?